# Is it possible to query and receive result when only part of the entity is indexed?

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch

My entity has the following fields - 
         Id, Name, Format, some other fields.
I send an entity to the ES.

I am querying elasticsearch - filtering by one entity property - name.
I get the entity in the result.

A split second later I query by other property - e.g. format.
I don't get my entity.

Then I sleep for three seconds.
I request the second query again (filter by format ).
I do get my entity.

**Is it possible to query and receive result when only a part of the entity is indexed**
(- and some other part will be indexed soon )?

(I know that when I add an attribute to a mapping I have to reindex the entity because the weights have to be updates. 
Therefor I don't understand querying  partial index )

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting [Near Real-Time Search problem](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/near-real-time.html). Call `POST /index_name/_refresh` immediately after indexing, but keep in mind that flushing is expensive.